# $\int_0^{200} \frac{1}{e^{5x}(x+20)}dx < \frac{1}{100} $

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

$\int_0^{200} \frac{1}{e^{5x}(x+20)}dx < \int_0^{200} \frac{1}{20e^{5x}}dx<\frac{1}{100} $ 
Is this solution correct?

Comment: $1/100-1/(100e^{1000})$

Comment: @qbert You asked why the last inequality was true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although filling in the gaps: For $x\geq 0$ we have 
$$
\frac{1}{e^{5x}(x+20)}\leq \frac{1}{e^{5x}20}
$$
Thus 
$$
\int_0^{200}\frac{1}{e^{5x}(x+20)}\mathrm dx\leq \frac{1}{20}\int_0^{200}\frac{1}{e^{5x}}\mathrm dx=(1-e^{-1000})\frac{1}{100}<\frac{1}{100}
$$